# Set JS Variable to href of clicked anchor dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I need to set a variable's value based on the href of a clicked link.

I know that I can set the variable using an event listener that would run this when the link is clicked

```
var x = document.getElementById("myAnchor").href
```

But that is set to a single element. I need it to work dynamically based on which link is clicked. For example:

```
<a href="/link1">Partner A</a>
<a href="/link2">Partner B</a>
<a href="/link3">Partner C</a>
```

```
// function to attach click event to all links
function attachClickEvent() {
  var linklist = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var listLength = linklist.length;
  var i = 0;
  for (; i < listLength; i++) {
    linklist[i].addEventListener("click", ClickedLinkEvent);
  }
}

window.onload = attachClickEvent;

// function that creates click event
function ClickedLinkEvent() {
  var anchor = obj.href;
  console.log(anchor);
  if (anchor.includes('clientdomain')) {
    //do nothing
  } else {
    SendLinkEvent();
  }
}

// function to run on click event
function SendLinkEvent() {
  ga('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: 'Affiliate Link',
    eventAction: 'Click',
    eventLabel: anchor
  });
}
```

The anchor variable needs to be set to /link1 if Partner A is clicked, but /link2 if Partner B is clicked.

So, is there a way to do this with vanilla JS?

Comment: Instead of `obj` in `ClickedLinkEvent`, use `this`.

Comment: `this` can point to different things, you don't have full control over it. When event is fired, it contains all event details. Try adding `e` argument to the handler: `ClickedLinkEvent(e)`. And check what is inside `console.log(e);`

Comment: @VladimirSerykh By spec, when a function is attached as shown in the code in the OP, `this` will refer to the element which is the current target of the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you adjust the `ClickedLinkEvent` method declaration and add an argument to the method signature, then you will have the event object. The event object has a *target* parameter. If I understood you correctly, this is what you need. Don't you?

```
function ClickedLinkEvent(e) {
    console.log('hello', e);
    var anchor = e.target.href;
    console.log(anchor);
    if (anchor.includes('clientdomain')){
       //do nothing
    }
    else {
         SendLinkEvent(anchor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom attributes to the a element like this:

```
<a href="..." id="myAnchor" data-partner="your_important_data_here">Link A</a>
```

Then in your js file:

```
var data_partner= document.getElementById('myAnchor').getAttribute('data-partner');
```